# Is there a way to get url present of an element who's value is < a href = "#">

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data  the website Bestbuy.com (USA),when we go to the product page URL for the first time It asks us to choose the country, [product page](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/philips-norelco-oneblade-wet-dry-electric-trimmer-lime-green-charcoal-gray/5271800.p?skuId=5271800). I am trying to get the URL of the page that directs to USA, when user clicks on United States flag

Note: You may try to open the link of product page in incognito window

The code snippet of the element on the retailers site, where we have to select the country is as follows:

```
<div class="country-selection">
<a href="#" class="us-link">
<img src="https://assets.bbystatic.com/international/landing_page/v2/images/maps/usa.svg" alt="United States">
<h4>United States</h4>
</a>
</div>
```

When i run the scrapy command to get the url of the element of href, I get the value as '#', which is correct

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]/@href').extract()
```

When i hover on the '#' in the source code, I can see the URL , how can i fetch this value?

Image>> [image Link](https://ibb.co/g3mqYtD)

Comment: Wouldn't be that the URI of the resource itself?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @Alejandro: Alright, you have a point there, could you tell me how could i find the product page URL then? I want the url of the page the user is directed to when he clicks on the flag of the country USA.

Comment: You can get the url of the current response on `response.url`

Answer (score 0):

As Luiz commented, `response.url` contains the current URL.

If you want to resolve relative URLs to absolute URLs in general, taking advantage of `response.urljoin()` or replacing `Request()` with `response.follow()` might be a better approach.